# How to unmount the plastic cover on a Gen 3 (2015) Honda Jazz bonnet?

Tags: honda, windshield-washer, jazz

**Context:** The driver-side washer nozzle (red arrow on the picture below) of my UK 2015 Honda Jazz is losing pressure (the jet is very weak). I want to investigate the cause myself.

To inspect the washer nozzle itself, I need to unmount the plastic cover (yellow highlight on the picture below) that protects them. I have found to screw to remove from under the hood, yet this isn't sufficient to remove the cover.
I can by gently bending the cover (but it's too tight to take a picture) that it is still attached to the bonnet via a green part that looks a bit like a flipper bumper but I've remained unsuccessful in trying to detach it. (I'm not sure whether there is something to unclip, press, or whether a bit more force is required…)

[image]

**Question:** how to detach from the bonnet/unmount the plastic cover (highlighted in yellow on the picture above) of my Gen 3 Honda Jazz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cowl (plastic cover) is two pieces. It is held in place by two bolts and a number of plastic clips. You can use a screw driver or a trim removal tool to remove the plastic clips.  See the diagram below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's very, very helpful! The diagram is also extremely valuable; would you be able to share its source? That would — hopefully — allow me to look at the details of parts #28 and #34: I'm indeed not sure whether to use the screwdriver as a lever, or whether I need to “twist” it.

Comment: Here is the source. Good luck!  https://www.hondapartsonline.net/v-2016-honda-fit--ex--1-5l-l4-gas/body-air-conditioning--engine-hood.